# Hamburger menu navigation items animations

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-transitions, animate.css

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LCS6Z-oP1rqPbRF7tydgVWZEdCEt_RPP/view?usp=sharing this the animation effect on hamburger menu navigation menu items.
On click on the hamburger menu there is animation going on each navigation menu items.
I have tried to recreate one. https://codepen.io/coral_Sb/pen/VwmQbLo I don't understand where I getting wrong?

The animation is playing everytime when hamburger menu is clicked.

```css
.nav-menu {
  background-color: red;
}

.nav-menu ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

li:first-child {
  animation: bringback 1s 0s forwards;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  animation: bringback 1s 2s forwards;
}

.nav-menu li:nth-child(3) {
  animation: bringback 1s 3s forwards;
}

.nav-menu li:nth-child(4) {
  animation: bringback 1s 4s forwards;
}

.nav-menu li:nth-child(5) {
  animation: bringback 1s 5s forwards;
}

.nav-menu li:nth-child(6) {
  animation: bringback 1s 6s forwards;
}

.nav-menu li:nth-child(7) {
  animation: bringback 1s 7s forwards;
}

.nav-menu li:nth-child(8) {
  animation: bringback 1s 8s forwards;
}

.nav-menu li:nth-child(9) {
  animation: bringback 1s 9s forwards;
}

.nav-menu li:nth-child(10) {
  animation: bringback 1s 10s forwards;
}

@keyframes bringback {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    text-indent: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-menu" id="nav-menu">

  <ul id=" check-ul" style="list-style:none">
    <li>
      <!-- class="active1"-->
      <span><img src="images/birla-logo.png" alt=""></span>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About us <span class="fas fa-sort-down mr-3" style="width: 20px;"></span> </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Curriculum</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Criteria</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Admission Process</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Careers </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact us </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Enquire Now </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use hardcoded CSS for stuff like: `li:nth-child(10)` etc. As soon you decide to add or remove one item from your HTML you should not as a developer go and touch your CSS files. Use css variables (style="--order:1") or JavaScript

Comment: I dont want to add or remove item rather I want to have animation effect on the hamburger menu items. The google drive link is provided above for reference.

Comment: I found an interesting video that talks about it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkKjrH3pRfg you might want to have a look at it. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Don't hardcode CSS for an arbitrary number of items li:nth-child(*N*) - **it's hard to maintain**.

### Sequentially staggered delay animation

Use **CSS variables** to create a staggered animation by using fill-mode `both` and control the delay using that CSS variable inside CSS `calc()`:

```css
#check-ul li {
  animation: animate 350ms ease calc(var(--i) * 200ms) both;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-2em);
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-menu" id="nav-menu">
  <ul id="check-ul">
    <li style="--i:1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li style="--i:2"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li style="--i:3"><a href="#">Curriculum</a></li>
    <li style="--i:4"><a href="#">Criteria</a></li>
    <li style="--i:5"><a href="#">Admission Process</a></li>
    <li style="--i:6"><a href="#">Careers </a></li>
    <li style="--i:7"><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    <li style="--i:8"><a href="#">Enquire Now</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### Trigger menu animations on open via button click:

```js
const toggleTarget = (sel) => {
  const EL_targets = document.querySelectorAll(sel);
  EL_targets.forEach(EL => EL.classList.toggle("is-active"));
};

const EL_toggleButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-toggle]");
EL_toggleButtons.forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
  toggleTarget(ev.currentTarget.dataset.toggle);
}));
```

```css
#nav-menu {
  position: fixed;
  background: #d00;
  color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

#nav-menu.is-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

#nav-menu.is-active li {
  animation: animate 350ms ease calc(var(--i) * 100ms) both;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-2em);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-toggle="#nav-menu">OPEN MENU</button>
<div id="nav-menu">
  <button type="button" data-toggle="#nav-menu">CLOSE</button>
  <ul>
    <li style="--i:1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li style="--i:2"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li style="--i:3"><a href="#">Curriculum</a></li>
    <li style="--i:4"><a href="#">Criteria</a></li>
    <li style="--i:5"><a href="#">Admission Process</a></li>
    <li style="--i:6"><a href="#">Careers </a></li>
    <li style="--i:7"><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    <li style="--i:8"><a href="#">Enquire Now</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Roko Thankyou for the above answer. Please let me also know that how to play this animation play everytime when we click on the hamburger menu

Comment: @Akankshakeshari in that case you could use JavaScript to add a class to the menu - I'll show you a quick example

Comment: @Akankshakeshari added an example.

Answer (score 0):

In order to complete a full example, I think you need some JavaScript in the mix.

Let's approach this problem by first creating the necessary components to properly display the navigation from the video:

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <button id="toggle-button">
  <svg class="menu-button" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
  </svg>
</button>
```

And style it accordingly:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}

#toggle-button {
  background: none;
    color: inherit;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    font: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: inherit;
}

.navigation {
  background: #1f2937;
}

.menu-button {
  color: white;
  width: 2.3rem;
  height 2.3rem;
}
```

What we need to do next is prepare the necessary markup for the panel, fader, and side menu.

```html
<div class="overlay-container hidden">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="panel">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="hidden" style="--i:1">Menu item #1</li>
        <li class="hidden" style="--i:2">Menu item #2</li>
        <li class="hidden" style="--i:3">Menu item #3</li>
        <li class="hidden" style="--i:4">Menu item #4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And of course style it:

```
.overlay-container.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.overlay-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.overlay.fade {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  background: black;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
}

.panel.slide {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.panel {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 18rem;
  background: #c00136;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 300ms ease-out;
}

.menu {
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu li.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.menu li {
  color: #f7f7f7;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.menu li.fadeInLeft {
  animation: fadeInLeft 350ms ease calc(var(--i) * 200ms) both;
}

@keyframes fadeInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-2em);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Now using this bit of javascript, you can orchestrate everything together. Notice how I used some transitions as well as animations so we can sequentially time

```
let button = document.getElementById("toggle-button");
let backbox = document.querySelectorAll('.overlay-container')[0];
let overlay = document.querySelectorAll('.overlay')[0];
let panel = document.querySelectorAll('.panel')[0];

/*
 * Since transitions from 'hidden'
 * to 'block' don't animate we need 
 * to trigger a browser repaint by
 * asking the element for it's height
 */
function forceRepaint(element) {
  return element.offsetHeight;
}

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  backbox.classList.remove('hidden');
  forceRepaint(backbox);
  overlay.classList.add('fade');
  panel.classList.add('slide');
});

panel.addEventListener("transitionend", function () {
  document.querySelectorAll('.menu li').forEach(node => {
    node.classList.remove("hidden");
    node.classList.add('fadeInLeft');
  })
});
```

I suggest you approach these problems gradually and step by step, that way you'll be able to solve these problems yourself in the future too. Problems like this seem complex at first, but it's essential that you break them down into smaller parts.

Finally, here's how it all comes together.

```js
let button = document.getElementById("toggle-button");
let backbox = document.querySelectorAll('.overlay-container')[0];
let overlay = document.querySelectorAll('.overlay')[0];
let panel = document.querySelectorAll('.panel')[0];

/*
 * Since transitions from 'hidden'
 * to 'block' don't animate we need 
 * to trigger a browser repaint by
 * asking the element for it's height
 */
function forceRepaint(element) {
  return element.offsetHeight;
}

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  backbox.classList.remove('hidden');
  forceRepaint(backbox);
  overlay.classList.add('fade');
  panel.classList.add('slide');
});

panel.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.menu li').forEach(node => {
    node.classList.remove("hidden");
    node.classList.add('fadeInLeft');
  })
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}

#toggle-button {
  background: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: inherit;
}

.navigation {
  background: #1f2937;
}

.menu-button {
  color: white;
  width: 2.3rem;
  height 2.3rem;
}

.overlay-container.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.overlay-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.overlay.fade {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  background: black;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
}

.panel.slide {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.panel {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 18rem;
  background: #c00136;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 300ms ease-out;
}

.menu {
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu li.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.menu li {
  color: #f7f7f7;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.menu li.fadeInLeft {
  animation: fadeInLeft 350ms ease calc(var(--i) * 200ms) both;
}

@keyframes fadeInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-2em);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <button id="toggle-button">
  <svg class="menu-button" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
  </svg>
  </button>

  <div class="overlay-container hidden">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="panel">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="hidden" style="--i:1">Menu item #1</li>
        <li class="hidden" style="--i:2">Menu item #2</li>
        <li class="hidden" style="--i:3">Menu item #3</li>
        <li class="hidden" style="--i:4">Menu item #4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
I used the snippet from Roko C. Buljan's answer to change my timing logic, as I was doing that with javascript and it makes the example so much simpler.

Comment: The animation should be played everytime when hamberger menu is clicked. I can't find that in your code.

Comment: Please take a look at my code pen: https://codepen.io/dev-cyprium/pen/YzpeVOq
@Akankshakeshari
The closing portion was not originally part of the question, if you want to see the full open/closing example please take a look at the code pen.

Comment: Simply put, the idea is to "add" and "remove" classes with javascript based on user interactions. I've simply included a vanilla JS example to demonstrate how you can achieve this effect.